# Changing linked library for a given executable (CentOs 6)

Tags: libraries, linker

I have an executable linked like this:

```
  $ ldd a.out
        libboost_system-mt.so.1.47.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.1.47.0 (0x00007f4881f56000)
        libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f4881cfb000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f4881965000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f488175d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4881540000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4881239000)
.
.
```

Where the libcrypto and libssl libraries are openssl 1.0.0-fips libs.  I want to experiment with the 1.0.1 libraries instead, and so I've built them in my home directory.  Is there a way to get `a.out` to relink against my new openssl libraries without a lot of pain?  I would like to avoid

- Having to relink `a.out` (because the build tools are massively complicated)
- Altering any global settings (because other devs work on this machine)

Is it possible to do what I'm hoping here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470600/changing-one-particular-shared-library-in-executable-binary

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> You can temporarily substitute a different library for this particular execution. In Linux, the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated set of directories where libraries should be searched for first, before the standard set of directories; this is useful when debugging a new library or using a nonstandard library for special purposes. The environment variable LD_PRELOAD lists shared libraries with functions that override the standard set, just as /etc/ld.so.preload does.
>   - [Shared Libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

You can also invoke the loader directly:

> /lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path `path` `executable`

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not override the default search path. I set it but ldd still shows me the system default path, not the overridden one.
Though I can force the loading of my own library by setting LD_PRELOAD.

Answer (score 25):

Write a wrapper script that sets the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. This is the pendant of `PATH` for shared libraries. The system search path is always searched after the directories listed in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. See the [dynamic linker manual](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld-linux.so.8.html) for reference.

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/opt/openssl-1.0.1/lib
exec /path/to/a.out "$@"
```

Or, for a one-off, directly on the command line:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/opt/openssl-1.0.1/lib ./a.out
```

Alternatively, if you want to modify the binary, try [chrpath](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Chrpath), which lets you edit the library search path baked in the executable.

Comment: +1 for `chrpath`. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: `$ chrpath ./mybinary -l` results in `./mybinary: no rpath or runpath tag found.`, thus it seems the only solution in this case is to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${PWD} ./mybinary` which works (provided the libraries it needs - as can be seen by `ldd mybinary | grep 'not found'` - are in the current directory). Any way to still change the binary in this case?

Comment: @RoelVandePaar I think `chrpath` can only edit an existing rpath, not add one if there isn't. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary/20333550#20333550) suggests that `patchelf` can add an rpath. I haven't tried.